# Path GetFileName swap / with \

Tags: c#, path

I have a problem where I am having MySQL DB where I store `htmlBody` text.

Html body text is text like html. Example:

```
<img src='https://www.Something.com/Images/SomeImage.jpg'>
<p>This is some image</p>
```

Now I have winform application where I built custom control which builds up html texts from normal winform elements. Problem comes when I extract elements properties from string loaded from MySQL.

I have string like this: `<img src='https://www.Something.com/Images/SomeImage.jpg'>`

In my function I detect it is image and I create new custom class for it and inside that class I have 2 elements like this:

```
public string srcPath { get; set; }
public string srcFileName { get; set; }
```

To extract path and name from my url (`https://www.Something.com/Images/SomeImage.jpg`) I use `Path` but when I do
`string filename = Path.GetDirectoryName(myUrl);` instead of `https://www.Something.com/Images` I get `https:\\www.Something.com\\Images`

As you can see on first sight it replaced `/` with `\\` which I could overcome by replacing it again but after `https` I had 2x // and instead replacing it each with 2x `\\` it did it only once so even if I do replace it simple way it wont work since it will create string like `https:/www.Something.com/Images`.

Solution for this I came with is to create custom function to overcome this which is not problem for me but I guess there must be better way of doing it.

Comment: URLs ***are not*** file paths.

Comment: @spender then how could I extract those two values?

Comment: The `URI` class should have some properties that would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

URIs are not file paths and treating them as such inevitably will lead to problems, as you have discovered. However, the `Uri` class has a `Segments` property that can help with this decomposition.

Combined with `UriBuilder` you can:

```
var uri = new Uri("http://a/b/c/d");
var ub = new UriBuilder(uri);
ub.Path = string.Concat(uri.Segments.Take(uri.Segments.Length - 1));
Console.WriteLine(ub.Uri.AbsoluteUri);
Console.WriteLine(uri.Segments.Last());
```

It's worth noting that the last segment of a URI isn't really a filename. The URI as a whole points to a resource.